# Разбить список ссылок по div'ам

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте.
Есть список ссылок вида `<a class="linkclass" href=""><span>text</span></a>`
ссылок таких в массиве данных может быть от нуля и до 28-30.
задача их сортировать по 7 штук в колонки, т.е.

`1 8
2 9
3 10
4 11
5 12
6 
7`

ну и так далее. единственное что пришло в голову, так это пихать их по 7 штук в div со свойством float:left.
Подскажите как-то сделать, находил варианты реализации, где в теле ul списков плодили таких блоки, но не годится.
также, надо чтобы они все имели один класс, но последний имел еще дополнительный (чтобы можно было центровать и у последнего отступ обнулить).

Исходно имеем:

```
<a class="linkclass" href="">1 text</a>
<a class="linkclass" href="">2 text</a>
<a class="linkclass" href="">3 text</a>
<a class="linkclass" href="">4 text</a>
<a class="linkclass" href="">5 text</a>
<a class="linkclass" href="">6 text</a>
<a class="linkclass" href="">7 text</a>
<a class="linkclass" href="">8 text</a>
<a class="linkclass" href="">9 text</a>
<a class="linkclass" href="">10 text</a>
<a class="linkclass" href="">11 text</a>
<a class="linkclass" href="">12 text</a>
<a class="linkclass" href="">13 text</a>
<a class="linkclass" href="">14 text</a>
<a class="linkclass" href="">15 text</a>
<a class="linkclass" href="">16 text</a>
<a class="linkclass" href="">17 text</a>
<a class="linkclass" href="">18 text</a>
```

Ниже пример **результата**, который мне нужен, цифры в ссылках я указал просто для наглядности, в реальности это названия категорий будут.

```css
.column {
  background: #cccccc;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.column-last {
  margin-right: 0px;
}
.linkclass {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <a class="linkclass" href="">1 text</a>
  <a class="linkclass" href="">2 text</a>
  <a class="linkclass" href="">3 text</a>
  <a class="linkclass" href="">4 text</a>
  <a class="linkclass" href="">5 text</a>
  <a class="linkclass" href="">6 text</a>
  <a class="linkclass" href="">7 text</a>
</div>
<div class="column">
  <a class="linkclass" href="">8 text</a>
  <a class="linkclass" href="">9 text</a>
  <a class="linkclass" href="">10 text</a>
  <a class="linkclass" href="">11 text</a>
  <a class="linkclass" href="">12 text</a>
  <a class="linkclass" href="">13 text</a>
  <a class="linkclass" href="">14 text</a>
</div>
<div class="column column-last">
  <a class="linkclass" href="">15 text</a>
  <a class="linkclass" href="">16 text</a>
  <a class="linkclass" href="">17 text</a>
  <a class="linkclass" href="">18 text</a>
</div>
```

Comment: @Jean-Claude , писал с телефона и не форматировал, исправил + добавил пример как должно выглядеть.

Comment: @Jean-Claude прочтите ещё раз, про 7 колонок я не говорил ничего, я сказал 7 ссылок в одной колонке (блоке). :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Обновлено**

```js
$(function() {

  var array = $('.linkclass');
  var temparray, chunk = 7;
  for (var i = 0, j = array.length; i < j; i += chunk) {
    temparray = array.slice(i, i + chunk);
    $('.result').append('<div class="column"></div>');
    $('.result div.column:last').append(temparray);
  }

  $('.result div.column:last').addClass('column-last');

});
```

```css
.column {
  background: #cccccc;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.column-last {
  margin-right: 0px;
}
.linkclass {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="linkclass" href="">1 text</a>
<a class="linkclass" href="">2 text</a>
<a class="linkclass" href="">3 text</a>
<a class="linkclass" href="">4 text</a>
<a class="linkclass" href="">5 text</a>
<a class="linkclass" href="">6 text</a>
<a class="linkclass" href="">7 text</a>
<a class="linkclass" href="">8 text</a>
<a class="linkclass" href="">9 text</a>
<a class="linkclass" href="">10 text</a>
<a class="linkclass" href="">11 text</a>
<a class="linkclass" href="">12 text</a>
<a class="linkclass" href="">13 text</a>
<a class="linkclass" href="">14 text</a>
<a class="linkclass" href="">15 text</a>
<a class="linkclass" href="">16 text</a>
<a class="linkclass" href="">17 text</a>
<a class="linkclass" href="">18 text</a>

<div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: Кажется вы не поняли, что мне нужно, изначально мы имеем пачку ссылок, не оформленных в блоки, просто список ссылок. Скрипт должен их завернуть в блоки по 7 штук, чтобы получить тот результат, который я привел в первом сообщении. :)

Comment: @Aaron обновил ответ.

Comment: спасибо, теперь как надо)